# Java Generic syntax with Comparable interface

Tags: java, generics, comparable

I am trying to implement a simple insertion sort algorithm and make it generic to all the instance of Comparable interface.

```
public static <E extends Comparable<E>> void InsertionSort( E [] array)
{
    for(int i = 1; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        E current = array[i];

        int k;
        for(k = i-1; k >= 0 && current.compareTo(array[k]) < 0 ; k--)
        {
            array[k+1] = array[k];

        }

        array[k+1]=current;

    }

    for(int l = 0; l < array.length; l++)
    {
        System.out.print(array[l]+" ");

    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

The problem I have is I don't know the differences between

```
 <E extends Comparable<E>>
```

and

```
 <E extends Comparable>
```

They both work but I don't know the reason for the first one.

Comment: and the best option is `<E extends Comparable<? super E>>`

Answer (score 7):

`E extends Comparable<E>` means that an instance of `E` can be compared to other objects of type `E`.

`E extends Comparable` means that an instance of `E` can be compared to...something.  It's a raw type, which is bad.  Don't do that.